# Trying to clone a stdClass

Tags: php, clone, stdclass

I'm trying to clone a stdClass object that have an attribut which is a DateTime. But it fails. It looks like the clone is not working. Should I wrote my own __clone() method?
What is wrong here?

The code:

```
$object = new stdClass;
$object->date = new DateTime();
var_dump($object->date);

$cloned = clone($object);
$object->date->modify('+1 day');
var_dump($cloned->date);
```

The output:

```
object DateTime (
    ->date = string (19) '2013-04-11 11:54:00'
    ->timezone_type = int 3
    ->timezone = string (13) 'Europe/Berlin'

object DateTime (
    ->date = string (19) '2013-04-12 11:54:00'
    ->timezone_type = int 3
    ->timezone = string (13) 'Europe/Berlin'
```

Comment: Why not? It's the day after (11th vs. 12th)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When cloning an object, all the object properties are simply *copied* over to a new instance of the object. In effect this:

```
$cloned = new stdClass;
$cloned->date = $object->date;
```

As you probably know, assigning an object to another variable does not duplicate the object; there's still just one object, now with two references to it.

To *deep-clone* an object you need to implement a custom class with the [`__clone` method](http://www.php.net/__clone) and manually `clone` any child objects of it.

Comment: There is a dirty hack to deep clone a stdClass:  

 $cloned = unserialize(serialize($object));

Answer (score 12):

How to "clone" a php **POSCO** (Plain Old StdClass Object) via cast chaining:

```
$cloneObj = (object) (array) $myPOSCO;
var_dump($cloneObj == $myPOSCO); // true
var_dump($cloneObj === $myPOSCO); // false
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, still references the original obj?

Answer (score -1):

There is another simplier option:

```
$object = new stdClass;
$object->date = new DateTime();
var_dump($object->date);

$cloned = clone $object;
$object->date->modify('+1 day');

var_dump($cloned->date);
var_dump($object->date);
```

The output must be:

```
    object DateTime (
        ->date = string (19) '2013-04-11 11:54:00'
        ->timezone_type = int 3
        ->timezone = string (13) 'Europe/Berlin'

    object DateTime (
        ->date = string (19) '2013-04-11 11:54:00'
        ->timezone_type = int 3
        ->timezone = string (13) 'Europe/Berlin'

    object DateTime (
        ->date = string (19) '2013-04-12 11:54:00'
        ->timezone_type = int 3
        ->timezone = string (13) 'Europe/Berlin'
```

Comment: See, I double checked this answer and worked for me, so I won't remove this answer because can help somebody.